# Criei formulário não responsivo. Como faço para torná-lo responsivo?

Tags: bootstrap, layout-responsivo

Resolvi inserir bootstrap, então inseri o conteúdo da minha página dentro da classe container, chamei o bootstrap no meu head e

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Mas ainda não funcionou...

Comment: Posta o formulário completo que você criou, tem pouca informação pra que alguém consiga te ajudar.

Comment: Bem vinda, Marina. Comece fazendo o [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona a **comunidade**. Para podermos te ajudar, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/266001/edit) sua pergunta e nos forneça um [MCVE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) pois apenas com o código que você colocou, não da pra identificar aonde está o **problema**.

Answer (score 1):

Marina estou incluindo essa resposta apenas para esclarecer para você como o **ViewPort** funciona e por que provavelmente o seu site não está responsivo mesmo com o **ViewPort** e o Bootstrap.

Primeiro veja como funciona o `<meta name="viewport">`

*O viewport é a área onde seu website aparece. É a área branca da janela quando você abre o browser. O viewport sempre vai ter o tamanho da janela. Mas a forma como os elementos são renderizados vai depender bastante do dispositivo.*

**A Meta Tag Viewport**

Use a meta tag viewport, introduzida pela Apple, e então adotada e desenvolvida por mais pessoas.

Ela se parece com isso:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="">
```

Dentro do *content=""* você pode entrar com uma série de valores separados por vírgula, mas vamos focar nos fundamentos agora.

Por exemplo, se o seu layout móvel é definido em 320px, você pode especificar o viewport dessa forma:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```

Para layouts flexíveis é mais prático basear a largura do seu viewport no dispositivo em questão, para igualar a largura do layout à largura do dispositivo você deve digitar:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Para se certificar que o seu layout será mostrado como você planejou, você pode definir o nível de zoom inicial. Isso, por exemplo:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
```

... irá garantir que, após a abertura, o layout será exibido corretamente em escala 1:1. Nenhum zoom será aplicado. Você pode ir mais longe e evitar qualquer zoom pelo usuário:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="maximum-scale=1">
```

> **Nota:** Antes de aplicar o parâmetro de maximum-scale, considere se você realmente deve estar impedindo que os usuários deem o zoom. Eles são capazes de ler tudo da melhor forma possível?

Outra opção é configurar o ViewPort direto pelo CSS, inclusive essa é a recomendação da Microsoft para o Internet Explorer (ie10 e superior)

```
@viewport{
    zoom: 1.0;
    width: device-width;
}
```

***Aqui tem dois excelentes artigos em português que serviram de referencia e vão te ajudar muito!***

https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/pt/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972

https://tableless.com.br/manipulando-metatag-viewport/

---

**Agora por que seu site mesmo com o Bootstrap não está responsivo.**

Pelo que vc falou muito provavelmente vc não está usando o sistema de **Grid** do Bootstrap. Apenas indexar o Bootstrap na `<head>` do site não adianta. Você tem que usar as *Classes* do **Grid System** para o conteúdo ficar responsivo.

Aqui tem um exemplo de como fica o HTML usando as ***Classes do Grid*** do Bootstrap, e abaixo uma imagem que corresponde a esse código

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      ...conteúdo da coluna 1...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      ...conteúdo da coluna 2...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      ...conteúdo da coluna 3...
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      ...conteúdo da coluna 4...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Repare que as ***Classes Originais do Grid do Bootstrap*** é que são as responsáveis por deixar o conteúdo que está dentro das `<div>` responsivo e adaptável nas telas

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
```

> ***Artigo em português pare você entender melhor o Sistema de Grid e as Classes que precisa usar***

https://edsonjunior.com/compreendendo-grid-do-bootstrap/

---

*Aqui está a documentação oficial do sistema de Grid do Bootstrap 3*

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

*Documentação do Grid do Bootstrap 4*

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/